# RelayCommand on view still being evaluated after ShowDialog is closed

Tags: c#, wpf

([Closest related question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4095037/when-does-the-ui-detach-from-commands))

I execute `LogInRequest()` which calls `LogInView.ShowDialog()`. That view has a Command called `VerifyLogInCommand`. When the Command is executed, it completes with `this.CloseAction()` which appears to close the Dialog. However, my breakpoint in that view's command's CanExecute method `VerifyLogInCanExecute` is still being hit after the dialog is closed (nonstop). I've tried setting the view to null after calling ShowDialog but no change.

Why is the Command/CanExecute still being evaluated when the window is closed/null?

**LogInView.xaml.cs**

```
public LogInOutView()
{
    InitializeComponent();

    // Data context
    IModule existingVM = SessionViewModel.Instance.ModulesOpen.Single(mod => mod.ModuleName == "LogIn");
    LogInViewModel livm = (LogInViewModel)existingVM;
    this.DataContext = livm;

    // Cancel Handler
    livm.CloseAction = new Action(() => this.Close());
}
```

**LogInViewModel.cs**

```
public Action CloseAction { get; set; }

private RelayCommand verifyLogInCommand;
public RelayCommand VerifyLogInCommand
{
  get
  {
    if (verifyLogInCommand == null)
    {
      verifyLogInCommand = new RelayCommand(
        param => VerifyLogInExecute(),
        param => VerifyLogInCanExecute);
    }
    return verifyLogInCommand;
  }
}

public void VerifyLogInExecute()
{
  // Validate Login
  Employee employee = ValidateLogin(Password);

  // Clear password field
  ResetExecute();

  // Return false if invalid login
  if (employee == null)
  {
    Result = LogInOutDialogResults.Cancel;
    ConfirmationView c = new ConfirmationView("Invalid Login!");
    c.ShowDialog();
    return;
  }

  // Set Result to LogIn status
  Result = LogInOutDialogResults.LogIn;

  // Set LastAuthorizedEmployee
  SessionViewModel.Instance.LastAuthorizedEmployee = employee;

  // Close View to go back where it was called
  this.CloseAction();
}

public bool VerifyLogInCanExecute
{
  get
  {
    // Password length restrictions
    if (!CheckRequiredPasswordLength(Password)) { return false; }
    return true;
  }
}

public static LogInOutDialogResults LogInRequest()
{
  // Show Login View
  LogInOutDialogResults LogInOutResult = LogInOutDialogResults.Cancel;
  LogInOutView LogInOutView = new LogInOutView()
  {
    Title = "Log In",
    ShowInTaskbar = false,
    Topmost = true,
    ResizeMode = ResizeMode.NoResize,
    Owner = SessionViewModel.Instance.ProfitPOSView
  };
  LogInOutView.ShowDialog();
  LogInOutResult = ((LogInViewModel)LogInOutView.DataContext).Result;

  // LogIn
  if (LogInOutResult == LogInOutDialogResults.LogIn)
  {
    LogInOutView = null;
    return LogInOutDialogResults.LogIn;
  }
}
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

If you are using the `RelayCommand` from MvvmLight, it implements its `CanExecuteChanged` event by forwarding subscriptions to `CommandManager.RequerySuggested`.  This effectively allows a `RelayCommand` to update its own status the way a `RoutedCommand` does in WPF; the `RequerySuggested` event fires on certain conditions, including every time the focus changes or a window is (de)activated.   The `RequerySuggested` event uses weak event handlers to mitigate leaked subscriptions, but the weak event implementation used by WPF isn't terribly diligent about cleaning up after itself, so the subscription may still remain active for a while (perhaps even indefinitely).

Your `CanExecute` callback *appears* to be reevaluating non-stop because every time you hit a breakpoint, Visual Studio steals focus from your application, and when you hit 'Resume', your application is reactivated, thus triggering the `RequerySuggested` event and causing `CanExecute` to be reevaluated.  That, in turn, triggers the breakpoint *again*, and you get caught in a cycle until you disable the breakpoint.

If your View Model is aware of its closed state, I would change your `VerifyLogInCanExecute` property to something like:

```
public bool VerifyLogInCanExecute
{
    get { return !IsClosed && CheckRequiredPasswordLength(Password); }
}
```

At least then you will not be doing more work than is necessary.  Another option would be to set your login command to `null` (or an empty/no-op command) when the View Model is closed (and raise the appropriate `PropertyChanged` event).  That will cause any buttons bound to the command to unsubscribe from its `CanExecuteChanged` event.

Comment: Thanks for the great explanation. I just found similar explanation of setting the Command to null when done [here as well](http://stackoverflow.com/a/6695530/1992193)

Comment: I've the same issue, however it happens in my project, even after I'm setting the command to null, any ideas?

Comment: @Chen are you raising `PropertyChanged` when you null-out your command?  If not, the bound control doesn't know the command has been replaced, and will continue to query the old one.

Comment: I've a view model that I'm trying to cleanup, one of the things that I do is to null all command. After the cleanup I get called in the can execute. What is the best way to avoid it? Thank you.

Answer (score 1):

Upon what Mike Storbl pointed out about Mvvm light's RelayCommand which uses

```
 CommandManager.RequerySuggested
```

which is very expansive performance wise , and is prone to allot of bugs since it raises

```
  CanExecuteChangedEvent
```

every time the VisualTree is focused .

You should implement your own  as such :

```
public class RelayCommand : ICommand
{
    private Func<bool> _canExecute;
    private Action _execute;

    public RelayCommand(Action execute , Func<bool> canExecute = null)
    {
        _execute = execute;
        _canExecute = canExecute;
    }

    public bool CanExecute(object parameter)
    {
        return _canExecute == null ? true : _canExecute();
    }

    public event EventHandler CanExecuteChanged;

    public void RaiseCanExecuteChanged()
    {
        var temp = Volatile.Read(ref CanExecuteChanged);

        if (temp != null)
            temp(this, new EventArgs());
    }

    public void Execute(object parameter)
    {
        _execute();
    }
}
```

and raise it from your code when needed , for instance when Password was changed.

```
  verifyLogInCommand.RaiseCanExecuteChanged();
```